# XSLT loop through two different child nodes sets and merge into one

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML similar to below format.

```
<travel>
<buses>
    <bus>
        <id>1</id>
        <to>A</to>
        <from>B</from>
    </bus>
    <bus>
        <id>2</id>
        <to>X</to>
        <from>Y</from>
    </bus>
</buses>
<passengers>
    <passenger>
        <busId>1</busId>
        <name>John</name>
    </passenger>
    <passenger>
        <busId>2</busId>
        <name>Smith</name>
    </passenger>
</passengers>
</travel>
```

There are two nodes under travel tag. Buses and passengers. They connect in bus id and busId in passenger nodes. I want to loop through all bus nodes and identify the associate passangers to given bus. Then create a new node under each bus called passengers and add those passenger nodes as it is to that as below.

```
<travel>
<buses>
    <bus>
        <id>1</id>
        <to>A</to>
        <from>B</from>
        <passengers>
            <passenger>
                <busId>1</busId>
                <name>John</name>
            </passenger>
        </passengers>
    </bus>
    <bus>
        <id>2</id>
        <to>X</to>
        <from>Y</from>
    </bus>
    <passengers>
        <passenger>
            <busId>2</busId>
            <name>Smith</name>
        </passenger>
    </passengers>
</buses>
```

There can be multiple passengers for each bus.

I though of using XSLT for this and seeking your help to come up with a proper XSLT sample. I really appreciate your help regarding this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply @michael.hor257k. I'm new to the XSLT. Can you please show me how to move node to other?

Comment: If you want to move a node you should select on the node you want to move the node to. There you should use <xsl:copy-of select='node/you/want/to/move'> now you only need to remove the node you want to move. But I don't know how to do that.